# Trigger Google Assistant SDK from Python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I'm running the Google Assistant SDK on RPi 3B.
To trigger the Assistant, I've set up a Python script that detects an input.
I have painfully little knowledge over Python, and have no clue how to trigger the Assistant from this script.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by trigger? And what input?

Comment: You can use os.system() to trigger a terminal command: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample

Comment: With 'trigger' I mean the equivalent of pressing 'enter' when the SDK is running. Is there a command I can execute within python/bash to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python *OS* function:

```
import os

os.system('/home/pi/env/bin/./python /home/pi/env/bin/google-assistant-demo')
```